# Different interpretations of a monoid as a category

Tags: category-theory, monoid

What is the relation between the categories $\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\mathbb{N}'_0$ as follows:
Both objects and arrows of $\mathbb{N}'_0$ are the natural numbers and f is an arrow $f:a\to b$ iff $f+a=b$. On the other side, $\mathbb{N}_0$ has the only object $*$ and the natural numbers are the arrows. $\mathbb{N}_0$ will be the standard interpretation of a monoid as a category. My question is:
$$\text{What is the relation between $\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\mathbb{N}'_0$}?$$
At first I thought the latter might be the arrow category of the first, but that arrow category is just trivial because there is only one object. After all, the only relation I see a forgetful functor from the latter to the first.

$$\text{Are there more interpretations of a monoid as a category?}$$

Comment: Your $\mathbb{N}'_0$ is a category in the standard way that any poset can be made into a category; and that only works because the natural numbers (with zero) are a [pomonoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_semigroup). So it's not a surprise that the functor is forgetful; a semigroup in general can be trivially ordered, which in this case would be every number being an object with an arrow only to itself; this $\mathbb{N}''_0$ is another boring category in which we forget the morphisms rather then the objects. From what I recall there's also a notion of ordered category...

Comment: The way $\Bbb N_0'$ is defined here, the arrow sets aren't disjoint. For $f=1$, we have $f\in Hom(1,2)\cap Hom(2,3)$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: This is not a problem if you implicitly assume that morphisms $f : A → B$ are ordered triples $(f, A, B)$ (this certainly needs to be done when defining arrow categories and comma categories in general), but you're right in pointing out that even if the solution is trivial, some people aren't aware that there's a problem at all.

Comment: @user54748: I know, one can always add domain and codomain to the triple and get distinct arrows. I just wanted to point out that one has to be careful when saying that the arrow set is $\Bbb N$. It's still in bijection with $\Bbb N$, though, but one has to convince oneself that there are only countably many arrows. And you're right, in comma categories one includes all information into the arrow that are needed to make the arrow sets disjoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> At first I thought the latter might be the arrow category of the
>   first, but that arrow category is just trivial because there is only
>   one object.

Well yes, but there's more than one arrow, and they're what the arrow category is about :)

Objects of the arrow category of a monoid $M$ are the elements of $M$, and a morphism between two elements $m$ and $n$ is a pair of elements $(k, l)$ such that $nk = lm$. Setting $k = e$ and $M = ℕ$, you get that your $ℕ'$ is a subcategory of the arrow category of $ℕ$.

Alternatively, a simpler description is that this is the ["coslice" category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Coslice_category) $*/M$ of objects under the unique object of $M$.
If $M$ is (left) cancellative, that category is a preorder, and as Respawned Fluff said, for $M = ℕ$ this is exactly the standard order $≤$ on $ℕ$.